# Interchange of limits of differential operators on differential forms

Tags: complex-geometry, differential-forms, complex-manifolds, exterior-derivative

Let $M$ be a complex 2-dimensional manifold with the additional property that a smooth function $h:M \to \mathbb C$ is constant if and only if $\partial\overline\partial h = 0$ (which is equivalent (if I'm not mistaken) to $M$ having only the constants as holomorphic functions).

Now we consider a family of smooth functions $f_n : M \to \mathbb C$. We know that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \partial\overline\partial f_n$$
converges locally uniformly to a (1,1)-form $g$. Further we know that for one $x_0 \in M$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x_0)$$
is convergent. Does this imply that
$$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$$
converges for all $x \in M$ to a smooth function $f$ with $\partial\overline\partial f=g$?

Comment: Oh, I guess that's a stupid question. For example if the $f_n$ are holomorphic we would get $g=0$.

Comment: I don't find your question stupid at all!

Comment: @Didier Thanks. So isn't my example with holomorphic functions a counter example?

Comment: I added an additional property about $M$. I guess now the question is stupid anymore.

Comment: Just curious, which complex manifold would satisfy that property?

Comment: @ArcticChar People who know better might correct me but I think we have the following: Functions in the kernel of $\partial\overline\partial$ are called pluriharmonic. It can be shown that a say real valued function is pluriharmonic if and only if it is the real part of a holomorphic function. If you now take a complex manifold on which the only holomorphic functions are the constants you should have it. All compact manifolds should have this property for example. But there are even more, for example Hilbert modular surfaces (after removing the singularities) because of the Koecher principle.